# How to disable arbitrary PHP 7 code in directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, mediawiki

**Question at the bottom.**

According to the [official Mediawiki security guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Security), I have to

```
<Directory "/Library/MediaWiki/web/images">
   # Ignore .htaccess files
   AllowOverride None

   # Serve HTML as plaintext, don't execute SHTML
   AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7

   # Don't run arbitrary PHP code.
   php_admin_flag engine off

   # If you've other scripting languages, disable them too.
</Directory>
```

However with Apache 2.4.29 and PHP 7.1.15 I get

```
Invalid command 'php_admin_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

According to [this post](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=52385&s=9c7914a5b4ba4292c4d23a49fbece934&p=269172#post269172) the solution is

> You cannot use php_admin_value/php_admin_flag with PHP compiled as CGI
>   (suPHP), because these options are only supported when PHP is compiled
>   as a module of Apache. Feel free to use php.ini sections to change the
>   settings (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php). Otherwise - just
>   switch to mod_ruid2+mod_php and you'll be able to use php_admin_value
>   in Apache configuration files.

Even when I have installed

```
dnf -y install httpd php php-mysqlnd php-gd php-xml php-mbstring mod_ruid2
```

I get the error, despite having `mod_php` and `mod_ruid2`.

**Question**

Can someone translate the above into what I actually need to do in my case in plain English?

Answer (score 0):

For a single directory:

```
    <Directory "/Library/MediaWiki/web/images">
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
```

For multiple directories under the same path:

```
    <DirectoryMatch ^/Library/MediaWiki/web/(images|other_folder|other_folder)>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </DirectoryMatch>
```

There's also <LocationMatch "path"> - more directives here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch